# msbuild - how to pre-pend string to each item in ItemGroup

Tags: msbuild

I have an item group and I need to pre-pend the same string to all of them (to get the correct paths).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo can use intermediate items to perform this modification. Let's call the pre-exiting items that need to be changed `MySpecialContent`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <_TmpMySpecialContent Include="@(MySpecialContent)" />
  <MySpecialContent Remove="@(_TmpMySpecialContent)" />
  <MySpecialContent Include="@(_TmpMySpecialContent->'my\prefix\%(Identity)')" />
</ItemGroup>
```