# msbuild - how to pre-pend string to ItemGroup without using intermediary (temp) value

Tags: msbuild

I have an item group and I need to pre-pend the same string to all of them (to get the correct paths).

My reason for needing this: I'm translating from `GNU make` to `MSBuild` and I'm trying to maintain a "1-to-1" mapping between the two 'makefiles'.

In the GNU makefile, there's use of [`addprefix` text macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) - which doesn't need a temp variable - so I want to replicate that "step" in the `MSBuild` "makefile".

How do I do that without using a temporary `ItemGroup`?

Comment: Please explain how you want to consume the items.. Because in case you just need the list as text or for a Copy or so you'd just use e.g. `<Message Text="@(SomeItems->'prepend%(Identity)')" />`

Comment: You asked a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534099), any reason why you don't want to use intermediary items?

Comment: @MartinUllrich style. It's annoying for me to have to create an intermediary.

Comment: @Adrian can you address my other comment as well? What do you want to do with the items, and can't you use something like the examples shown?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. You just answered what & why you want to do (pre-pend) but we knew that already and it doesn't help in producing an answer. I want to know what you are going to do with the resulting items. Because if you somehow must have the same ItemGroup again without temporary then AFAIK the answer is: you cannot do that (directly; you could add the result as metadata which doesn't require a temporary). But if you just need to use the result once then there's no reason to modify the item in-place and you can use the syntax shown.

Comment: @stijn then I guess it can't be done. I want to have the same ItemGroup again.